# C# break string at specific location

Tags: c#, string

I'm having a string,for example: **Ice cream   2x    2,35€**
How can I get only the price from string ? One way would be to get last 4 characters but its not necessary to have only 4digits, price can be also (12,12 ...).

I would need a method to go from back of a string till first space, but how?

Comment: You are probably looking for `price.LastIndexOf(' ')`

Comment: `var price = s.Split().Last();`

Answer (score 3):

You could use this regular expression:

```
(.*?)\d+\s*x\s*\d+(,\d+)?
```

- The first part `(.*?)` takes the product name
- `\d+` takes the amount
- `\d+(,\d+)?` takes the price (It may be just `2`, but `2,35` is allowed too)

  - The `\s*` in between is to take spaces in account

You can use [`Regex.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the values out.

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "Ice cream 2x 2,35€";

MessageBox.Show(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(' ')));
```

Should work

```
String.LastIndexOf
```

is what you need to find the last space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.LastIndexOf (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0w96zd3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and Substring

code:

```
 var pos = aa.LastIndexOf(' ')
 var part = aa.Substring(pos)
```

Comment: You don't need the second parameter for `string.Substring` as it has an overload that takes the starting position and goes to the end of the string.

Comment: Removed the unneeded second Parameter

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any googleing around this subject? There are various options available to you ranging from built in string methods through to Regular Expression.

Based on your thoughts in your question, I would start with this link: [String.LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)